# how to fetch Mysql data by like %column name%

Tags: mysql

the concept is for matching user relation and fetch post from timeline table

Table: Timeline {id,title,privacyTimeline}
Table: friend_request{id,requestType,status,from_id,to_id}

i am trying to fetch where privacy and requestType match but there is value in separated by comma 
privacyTimeline = 'family,friends'
requestType ='family'

i have wrote this query but not work with like'%%'

```
SELECT t.id,t.title
FROM timeline t JOIN
     friend_request fr
WHERE (fr.from_id = '3' OR fr.to_id='3') AND
      (t.privacyTimeline LIKE '%f.requestType%')
```

does not work

but its work when i replace column name fr.requestType to siple text 'family'
SELECT t.id,t.title FROM timeline as t JOIN friend_request as fr WHERE(fr.from_id = '3' OR fr.to_id='3') AND(t.privacyTimeline LIKE '%family%')

**please anyone who can guide me**

Comment: Fix your data structure to use a proper junction table, rather than storing lists of things in strings.  Storing lists in strings is simply a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [string concatenation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
t.privacyTimeline LIKE CONCAT('%', f.requestType, '%')
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Llama its work , i don't have sufficient reputation to up-vote but thank you .

Comment: @AhmadSayeed - You should still be able to accept the response as an answer.  It's the check symbol underneath the up and down arrows.  Glad I could help!